# Protractor - waiting for async to finish

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, asynchronous, protractor

In our application we are calling every minute to our feature flags service using angular therefore browser.waitForAngular() always fail.

is there a way to use browser.waitForAngular() and make it ignore this specific feature flag call (API call that is being called every 60 secs) so we can still use the wait for angular and not implement waits on the code?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to enable/disable waitForAngular which may be used to disable for pages where polling is happening and enabled again later for other pages..Check the below link

[browser.waitForAngularEnabled](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled)